# Spring data JPA update multiple rows

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

purpose: update some columns of same table by given list of primary keys and return ordered int[] to indicate if a row update is successful or not

query (not native):

```
update MyEntity e set e.col_1 = :v1, e.col_2 = :v2 where e.id in :ids
```

Spring Data JPA method:

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
@Transactional
public int updateCols(@Param("v1") String v1, @Param("v2") String v2, @Param("ids") List<Long> idList);
```

Spring JpaTransactionManager is used

Questions: 1) With Spring Data JPA only, how to do that? (customize repository not an option due to large existing codes), we want to achieve effects equivalent to JDBC batch update with Spring data JPA only.

2) Is it possible that spring data JAP will return an integer by the update method above that is less then the input list size? If that could happen, how do we know which one on my input list failed? In any order?

3) Noticed that after the above method successfully finished, database rows not being updated at all. How could we force it synchronized with database with spring data jpa?

4) If the entity update not flushed by spring data JPA, then even we update one by one instead of in a batch, still we will not see database changes?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First of all, AFAIK Spring Data JPA can't exist on its own, it's just a thing build upon bare JPA. It needs to use Hibernate or any other JPA provider under the hood.

https://github.com/colonder/Spring-Hibernate-JavaFX-Invoices

Have a look at my repository. It's Hibernate + Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA + Java FX 8, but I think it'll help you a little. My repo follows MVC pattern and uses Spring transaction manager, just like yours. As regards question 3 and 4 AFAIK Hibernate (because that's what Spring Data JPA use in my case as a provider) updates rows in the DB, not in the app. The problem should be that updated rows in the DB are not visible in the app, not the opposite.

Answer (score -1):

```
@Query("select t from SixxxoView t where t.idbien IN (:idbienes) ")
 public List<SixxxoView> findByIdbienes(
         @Param("idbienes") List<Long> idbienes);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be nice if you were to explain why your answer is better than those already provided.